# BuddyPress, get url (link) of a group using the group id

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I'am getting the id of a group using:

```
$group = groups_get_group( array( 'group_id' => $id) );
```

But for the life of me I can't figure out how to return the link to the group its self.

I can grab the slug, but some groups are sub groups so I can't just:

```
echo 'domain/groups/'.$group->slug;
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try:

```
bp_get_group_permalink( $group );
```

That will return the href value for the group. 
To get an html link use:

```
bp_get_group_link( $group );
```

Comment: D'oh, thank you. I have been searching for this function for hours!

Comment: what is `$group`? is it group id or it's just a global variable?

Comment: According to the code $group its the Group object:
`@param BP_Groups_Group|null $group Optional. Group object.
 Default: current group in loop.`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still needing the answer to why bp_get_group_permalink( $group ); doesn't work with just the group id, its because you need to create a Buddypress Group Object. Something like this:

```
    $group_obj = groups_get_group ( $group_id );
    $href = bp_get_group_permalink( $group_obj );
```